# I'm unable to understand this proof of the sum property of limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

In Apostol's Calculus Vol. 1 (pg. 136), the author gives a proof for the statement "if $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=A \;\&\;\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=B$, then we must have $\lim_{x\to p}[f(x)+g(x)]=A+B$

His approach is to first prove this statement for the case $A,B=0$, i.e he shows that "if $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=0$ & $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=0$, then we must have $\lim_{x\to p}[f(x)+g(x)]=0$".

He then states that the general case, $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$, follows from this special case because of two facts:

1. $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=A$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to p}[f(x)-A]=0$
2. $[f(x)-A]+[g(x)-B]=f(x)+g(x)-(A+B)$

Now, I understand that these two facts are true, and I can follow every step in the proof for the special case $A,B=0$, but I just don't see how we can go from the special case to the general case.

The only way I can make *some* sense of this is through the following (seemingly flawed) argument that I've come up with:

Since $$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=0\;\&\;\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=0 \implies \lim_{x\to p}[f(x)+g(x)]=0$$
We can let $f(x)=f(x)-A$ and $g(x)=g(x)-B$, then plug $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ into the above statement to find that:
$$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)-B=0\;\&\;\lim_{x\to p}g(x)-B=0 \implies \lim_{x\to p}[[f(x)-A]+[g(x)-B]]=0$$
which, because of the two general facts, is equivalent to the statement:
$$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=B\;\&\;\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=B \implies \lim_{x\to p}[f(x)+g(x)]=A+B$$

But to me it seems nonsensical to let $f(x)=f(x)-A$ and $g(x)=g(x)-B$ in a proof for all $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$; we could only do this for $A,B=0$, and so this argument falls apart.

Apostol himself doesn't go into detail about how these two facts imply the general case, which must mean that I'm missing something obvious.. or is it that the flawed argument is on the right track and I have just made some mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is asking you to replace $f(x) \rightarrow f(x)-A$ and $g(x) \rightarrow g(x)-B$, in order to have two functions with limit $0$ as $x$ approaches $p$, so you can then use the particular case already proven.
Let me give you some more details. If $\lim_{x \to p}f(x) = A$ and $\lim_{x \to p}g(x) = B$, define $F(x) := f(x)-A$ and $G(x) := g(x)-B$, and note that $\lim_{x \to p}F(x) = \lim_{x \to p}G(x) = 0.$ Now we can use what we already know to see that
$$0 = \lim_{x \to p}[F(x)+G(x)] = \lim_{x \to p}[f(x)+g(x) - (A+B)],$$
from which we finally conclude that
$$\lim_{x \to p}[f(x)+g(x)] = A+B = \lim_{x \to p}f(x)+\lim_{x \to p}g(x).$$

Comment: This approach confuses me because it seems as if we are defining $f(x)=f(x)-A$ and $g(x)=g(x)-B$ and plugging it in.. but isn't this always untrue for any $A,B$ not equal to $0$? Does this have something to do with confusing the meaning of "$=$" and "$:=$"?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui The symbol ":=" just means "the left side is defined by the right side", so your confusion doesn't come from there, don't worry. You're trying to set $f(x)$ equal to $f(x)-A$, and this simply doesn't work. What the author proved is the case in which both functions have limit $0$, which was the case $A = B = 0$, and now for the general case he wants you to *replace* the roles that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ previously had, using the functions $f(x)-A$ and $g(x)-B$, where now $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary limits, *but not the same ones as before*. He just reuses the letters.

Comment: What I don't understand is how we can replace the roles that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ previously had with the functions $f(x)-A$ and $g(x)-B$.. Isn't this just exactly the same as setting $f(x)=f(x)-A$ and $g(x)=g(x)-A$? Sorry if I'm repeating myself, I just can't wrap my head around this exact part of the proof.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui Maybe it's best to retract from the specific letters or functions used in the first part of the proof. Put into words, the author proved that "whenever you have two functions with limit $0$ as $x$ approaches $p$, the sum of those functions also has limit $0$ as $x$ approaches $p$". This statement can be proved without reaching for any numbers $A$ and $B$. With this knowledge, you can prove the general case by saying "now I take two arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$, with limits $A$ and $B$ respectively, and consider $f(x)-A$ and $g(x)-B$, and try to use what I already know".

Comment: Describing the statement with only words helped clarify things for me. Thanks for the extended help.